# Как правильно перевести процедуру Delphi в функцию c#?

Tags: c#, delphi

Имеется вот такая процедура чтения строки из бинарного файла(Delphi):

```
procedure TTextField.Load(f:PText);
var tempstr:widestring;
    c,q,m,t:integer;
begin
   Clear;
   BlockRead(f^,m,sizeof(m));
     for q:=1 to m do 
        begin
            BlockRead(f^,t,sizeof(t));
            SetLength(tempstr,t);
            for c:=1 to t do 
                BlockRead(f^,tempstr[c],sizeof(tempstr[c]));
            Text:=Text+#13#10+tempstr;
        end;
end;
```

Мне надо ее перевести на C#. Сделал вот так:

```
public static string TTextFieldLoad(BinaryReader br)
    {

        int c = 0, q = 1, m = 0, t = 0;
        char[] tempstr = new char[1];
        while (true)
        {
            if (br.ReadInt32() == 1)
                break;
        }
        int l = br.ReadInt32();
        tempstr = br.ReadChars(l);
        return tempstr.ToString();
    }
```

Но выдает мусор. Возможно, я не от туда читаю. Гляньте вообще, соответствие. А то я в Delphi не бум-бум...

Вот мой код, который сработал.

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("E:\\Users\\DezmontDeXa\\Desktop\\Tge\\PlanetQuestSP1\\Prison.qm", FileMode.Open);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        br.ReadBytes(82);//Перемещаюсь на позицию, откуда начинается текст
        int strCount = br.ReadInt32();
        string str = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < strCount; i++)
        {
            int strLen = br.ReadInt32();
            for(int c = 0; c < strLen; c++)
            {
                char ch = Encoding.Unicode.GetChars(br.ReadBytes(2))[0];
                str += ch;
            }
        }
        return str;
```

Comment: А если не секрет, зачем таким заниматься, какой смысл в этом?

Comment: Мне дали исходник редактора текствоых квестов. Квесты сохраняются в в бинарнике. Я хочу сделать расспаковщик этих квестов. Разрабы не против(сами предоставили исходник).

Comment: Просто delphi совсем не знаю, а хочется использовать квесты.

Comment: Да потом я уже сам понял, когда увидел что речь про бинарник идет. Тогда смысл понятен.

Comment: `char[] tempstr = new char[1];` - довольно опасное решение. Вы гарантированно вылезете за длину буфера, и, возможно, затрете другие данные или получите ошибку access violation

Comment: Благо в c# мне такие буферы не нужны)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот перевод с Delphi на русский.

```
Прочитать из файла 4 байта, записать в m (это количество строк)
Нижеследующий текст повторить m раз
  Прочитать из файла 4 байта, записать в t (это количество символов в следующей строке)
  Установить у временного буфера tempstr длину t
  Нижеследующий текст повторить t раз
    Прочитать из файла 2 байта, интерпретируя их как символ в двухбайтового UNICODE, записать в буфер tempstr.
  Добавить в выходной буфер text полученную в tempstr строку и символ перевода каретки.
```

Comment: ААа! Я думал m - длина строки. А тут оказывается несколько строк. Сейчас попробую)

Comment: Это помогло. Спасибо! Все остальное там вроде просто читается. А вот с этим текстом бился сутки)

Comment: Считывать из файла строки посимвольно - не надо так...